# Two Partial Views in One Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

[image]I tried to use 2 partial views under 1 view/page - first half page for search filters & 2nd half page for table display. Its working also,but the issue is the white color content panel is in fixed size. i.e., if my table got data it comes out of the white color panel.

```
<section class="content admin_table">
   @RenderBody()
</section>
```

I use above class in Layout. In Index View, I render both Partial views. My code part is below

```
 @Html.Partial("_view1", Model.Filter)
 @Html.Partial("_view2", Model.Result)
```

My IndexPage

```
@model SW.Web.ViewModels.CommonVM
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout1.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Title";
    ViewBag.Header = "Details";
       }
<link href="~/Content2/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!DOCTYPE html>

@section JavaScript{

<Script> .....</script>
<Script> .....</script>
}
@Html.Partial("_view1", Model.Filter)
 @Html.Partial("_view2", Model.Result)
```

and My Partial view 1

```
 @model SW.Web.ViewModels.viewmodel1 
     @{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Details", FormMethod.Post, new { d= Model }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <div>.....Design</div>
}
```

and my partial view 2

```
 @model IEnumerable<SW.Web.ViewModels.Viewmodel2>
    @{
     <div> Designs for partial view 2</div>

}
```

Comment: Change '@Html.Partial' to '@Html.RenderPartial'

Comment: So what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Ephraim I use these Partial views in single page along with layout. Its working, but my design got white color panel.the panel in fixed length,actually I want the panel to be expand according to the two views. Check the image I upload

Comment: You need to show your HTML code rather than just Partial View Code. You code doesn't make any sense

Comment: This is either an html or css issue. You need to show us what's inside your page.

Comment: I use two View model under single common view model as collection. In Index.cshtml page I call the common model and I wrote Scripts only and at the end of the index page, I called those 2 partial views(can see in my question). In partial View 1, I called view model 1 along with layout and just design the page in <div>. Likewise, I call the view model 2 for partial view 2 along with layout and just did design in <div>.

Comment: coding part is too big ..that's Y never post here.. also if I try like         { 
 @Html.Partial("_view1", Model.Filter)
 @Html.Partial("_view2", Model.Result)  }   --this one working but my curly braces also displays on my web page ..

Comment: You can post your codes on other sites like pastebin and link it here.

Comment: @Ephraim hi I update my question above.. Designs and scripts all working properly.. so I never write design and scripts details .. but this is my format now .. view name 1 is _view1 and 2 is _view2.. all working correctly.. only the backside panel never expand..

Comment: If your white color panel has a fixed size, you can add the css `overflow: auto;` so that the content (table) will not exceed the panel.

Comment: how is the Layout of your page like? I'm guessing that's where issue will be. If the left handside of your page is the menu and the white bit is a the page content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. by `controller action`

**@Html.Action("action1", "Controller", new { id = Model.idOfPart1 })**

**@Html.Action("action2", "Controller", new { id = Model.idOfPart2 })**

2. by `rendering view`

**@ Html.Render ("ParialView1", Model.model1)**

**@ Html.Render ("PartialView2", Model.model2)**

Answer (score 2):

I understand this is over a year old but just in case someone stumbles across this post.
RenderPartialView is written like the following:

```
@{@Html.RenderPartial("_yourPartial", yourModel)}
```

Answer (score 1):

So create One view with 
Search partial view like

```
//Serach view
<div class="white">
<h2>Search view</h2>
<--! search coading-->
   @Html.RenderPartial("Table_View", objectvalue2);
</div>
```

Use below line

```
 @Html.RenderPartial("_SearchView", objectvalue1);
```

in another page

Comment: U means Just add semicolon at the end? I tried this one already. Its not working,My panel doesn't extend and also the semicolon displays on my web page while running

Comment: what you exactly want to do ?

Comment: Hi @Suraj Khanra , thank you, but I dont want to do like this , currently my one is working , if I add curly braces before and after render partial view also fix my issue, but that braces also displays on the designed web page. I wanna fix that only ..